# Powershell command to copy only text files

Tags: powershell

I am trying to write a Powershell command to identify and copy only text (.txt) files from within a directory and sub-directories of that directory.  Does anyone know if there is a command that can perform this task.

Comment: easy if by extension only, not as easy if by content type detection.

Answer (score 7):

If you're not worried about maintaining the directory structure you could use

```
Get-ChildItem *.txt -recurse | Copy-Item -destination c:\qwerty
```

If you would like to maintain the directory structure you could use

```
Copy-Item  -Recurse -Filter *.txt  -path c:\temp -destination c:\asdf
```

NB.
The PowerShell `get-help` command is very useful and it does except wildcards.
ie
`get-help *copy*` gives you a list of commands that might be useful to you.
`get-help Copy-Item -full` gives you all the parameters plus examples of usage.